# StackOverflowError on DoWhile-loop. loop is not terminating?

Tags: java, loops

I have my first IT-course and wanted to practice loops and have a overstackflowerror on the DoWhile-loop. it says the problem is the return line at the end.

The task: a program that can calculate your capital with compound interest. The input of the users are the start capital, the interest rate and the duration.

My tutor helped me at the While-loop and the Recursion-loop, but I fail at the DoWhile-loop.

```
(Laufzeit = duration, zinssatz = interest rate)
```

I dont understand why the loop shouldnt terminate. it should add 1 to counter `(counter ++)` till its as high as the duration `(while (counter <= laufzeit)` and then stop right?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zinseszins {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Geben Sie das Startkapital ein.");
    double startkapital = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Geben Sie den Zinssatz ein.");
    double zinssatz = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Geben Sie die Laufzeit ein.");
    int laufzeit = sc.nextInt();

    sc.close();

    double end = endkapitalDoWhile( startkapital, zinssatz, laufzeit);
    System.out.println("DoWhile-Schleife: " + end);

}
public static double endkapitalDoWhile(double startkapital, double zinssatz, int laufzeit) {
int counter = 1;
    do {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            zinssatz = zinssatz + 0.1;
        } else{
            zinssatz = zinssatz;
        }
        startkapital = startkapital + (startkapital *(zinssatz/100));
        counter++;
        return (endkapitalDoWhile(startkapital, zinssatz, laufzeit));
    } while (counter <= laufzeit);
}
```

Comment: You are recursively calling `endkapitalDoWhile` in a loop. Why?

Comment: When i deleted the line i got an error. It said that this method must return a result of type double. I then remembered that my tutor did sth similar in the other loops and tried to recreate it.

Comment: This is not "StackOverflowError on DoWhile-loop."  This is "StackOverflowError on runaway recursion".  And with runaway recursion, that's what you get: StackOverflowError.

Comment: (note the subtlety in my recursive answer.)

Comment: Sorry if I act stupid, but the problem is I dont understand why this method must return a result of type double. I think I understood now that its starting the loop from the beginning because I tell him to return there right? How can i fix the error without the loop restarting? I dont want it to return anywhere. Just do the loop till counter <= laufzeit, thats what I want to tell him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to practice Do-while loop. The problem here is that you are returning the data before the do-while loop is finishing and calling the same function. As a result, an infinite recursion is taking place.

Change your code as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Capital");
    double startcapital = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter Interest Rate");
    double interest_rate = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter Year");
    int duration = sc.nextInt();

    sc.close();

    double end = endkapitalDoWhile(startcapital, interest_rate, duration);
    System.out.println("DoWhile-Schleife: " + end);

}
public static double endkapitalDoWhile(double startcapital, double interest_rate, int duration) {
int counter = 1;
    do {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            interest_rate = interest_rate + 0.1;
        } else{
            interest_rate = interest_rate;
        }
        startcapital = startcapital + (startcapital *(interest_rate/100));
        counter++;            
    } while (counter <= duration);      

    return startcapital;
}
```

It should give you the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried this before but the answer was wrong.                                 
While-Schleife: 11944.944111620372
Rekursion-Schleife: 11944.944111620372
DoWhile-Schleife: 11968.25131964305, but at least It didnt give me an error. Thank you

Comment: I took 10000 for startcapital, 2,5 for the interest and 7 for the duration

Comment: @Cali, the do-while loop is perfectly fine. I also tried it with While Loop, it gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

**StackOverflowError** is due to recursive function you are calling inside loop.

You simply return value after **While** condition and your problem will be solved.

```
public static double endkapitalDoWhile(double startkapital, double zinssatz, int laufzeit) {
 int counter = 1;
    do {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            zinssatz = zinssatz + 0.1;
        } else{
            zinssatz = zinssatz;
        }
        startkapital = startkapital + (startkapital *(zinssatz/100));
        counter++;

    } while (counter <= laufzeit);   
 return startkapital ;   
    }
```

Change the return value if you want to return something else.
Hope it will work for you .

Happy Coding !

Comment: Hi, I tried this before but the answer was wrong.                                 
While-Schleife: 11944.944111620372
Rekursion-Schleife: 11944.944111620372
DoWhile-Schleife: 11968.25131964305, but at least It didnt give me an error. Thank you

Comment: I have mentioned to change the return value according to your logic.

Comment: You can mark answer correct if it worked for you Thanks.